# Read all Numbers from a given txt and output them in a new file in c

Tags: c, file, numbers

I'm pretty new into Stackoverflow, therefore I'm sorry if it aint appropriate what I'm asking.  My question here is, how can I read all numbers from a given txt file (finp in my code) and output them into a new file. I did all I know, but somehow I cant come to a solution to read out all numbers. I can output them but as said, it isnt equal to the numbers in the text file.  I hope someone here can help me. TY
(I did manage to output all letters from the txt, but those numbers are making my life hard..)

Comment: `int numbers[0];` shouldn't compile. Is that meant to be `numbers[100]` or something?

Comment: I surely did something wrong there, dont mind those variables, as I tried stuff out, basically what I need is a code which reads all numbers out, and I dont know how I could solve that.

fprintf(foutp, "\nVorkommenden Zahlen und ihre Häufigkeit sind:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<7;++i) {
               fprintf(foutp, "%c: %02d  ", (int)(1 + i), numbers[(i*7)+i]);

This was my try but as I see that didnt went quite well...

Comment: Your code should at least compile and print something. You also have to show input, output, and expected output, and please explain the specific problem you are having.

Comment: As said, my problem is, I need to output all numbers in a specific Text File im inputing. I did already the output of all letters, which is working, but my I dont know how to output or read numbers from a txt file im giving.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your 'numbers' array has no size (it should be at least 10), you are not collecting any information about numbers when reading the text file. You are collecting info about the letters only.

```
while (*curr != '\0') {
    if (*curr >= 'A' && *curr <= 'Z') {
        alphabet[*curr-'A']++;
    } else if (*curr >= 'a' && *curr <= 'z') {
        alphabet[*curr-'a']++;
    }
}
```

I would write that part like this:

```
while(*curr != '\0')
{
    if(isupper(*curr)
        alphabet[*curr - 'A']++;
    else if(islower(*curr)
        alphabet[*curr - 'a']++;
    else if(isdigit(*curr))
        numbers[*curr - '0']++;       
}
```

Now I have downloaded your program and edited it. I am sending you my changes. Now the source can be compiled and also works with numbers. You will probably have to adapt it to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TEXT_STATS "text_stats.txt"     // Ausgabe in die gewünschte Datei
#define MAX_STRG 100                   // Länge String - Maximum
#define MAX_LINE 100                  // Länge Line - Maximum

int main (void)
{

    char input[MAX_STRG], read[MAX_LINE];
    int x = 0, lines = 0, alphabet[26] = {0}, numbers[10] = {0};
    size_t newline = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Hier Namen der Datei oder den Pfad eingeben: ");
        if (fgets(input, MAX_STRG, stdin) == NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        newline = 0;
        while (input[newline] != '\0' && input[newline] != '\n' && newline < (int)sizeof(input))
            newline++;
        if (newline == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (newline >= (MAX_STRG-1)) {
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            fprintf(stderr, "Maximum length is %d\n", MAX_STRG);
            continue;
        }
        input[newline] = '\0';
        break;
    }

    FILE *finp = fopen(input, "r");
    if (finp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Datei kann nicht geöffnet oder gefunden werden!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(read, MAX_LINE, finp) != NULL) {
        char *curr = read;

        size_t newline = 0;
        while (curr[newline] != '\0' && curr[newline] != '\n' && newline < MAX_LINE)
            newline++;
        if (newline < (MAX_LINE-1)) {
            lines++;
        }
        curr[newline] = '\0';

        while (*curr != '\0') {
            if (isupper(*curr))
                alphabet[*curr-'A']++;
            else if (islower(*curr))
                alphabet[*curr-'a']++;
            else if (isdigit(*curr))
                numbers[*curr - '0']++;
            x++;
            curr++;
        }
    }

    FILE *foutp = fopen(TEXT_STATS, "w");
    if (foutp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Datei kann nicht geöffnet oder gefunden werden!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fprintf(foutp, "Statistic for the text file \"%s\":\n", input);
    fprintf(foutp, "== A total of %d characters in %d lines ==\n", x, lines);
    fprintf(foutp, "\nLetters:\n");
    {
        int Len = sizeof(alphabet) / sizeof(int);
        int cols = 4, rows = (Len / cols) + ((Len % cols) ? 1 : 0);
        typedef int (*biar)[rows];
        biar iPtr = (biar)alphabet;
        for(int j = 0, k = 0, pos = 0; (cols * j) < Len; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0, pos = (rows * k) + j; pos < Len; pos = (rows * ++k) + j)
                fprintf(foutp, "%c: %3d    ", pos + 'a', iPtr[k][j]);
            fprintf(foutp, "\n");
        }
    }
    fprintf(foutp, "\nNumbers:\n");
    {
        int Len = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);
        int cols = 4, rows = (Len / cols) + ((Len % cols) ? 1 : 0);
        typedef int (*biar)[rows];
        biar iPtr = (biar)numbers;
        for(int j = 0, k = 0, pos = 0; (cols * j) < Len; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0, pos = (rows * k) + j; pos < Len; pos = (rows * ++k) + j)
                fprintf(foutp, "%c: %3d    ", pos + '0', iPtr[k][j]);
            fprintf(foutp, "\n");
        }
    }

    fprintf(foutp, "\nVorkommenden Zahlen und ihre Häufigkeit sind:\n");
    printf("Die gewünschte Aufstellung wurde in %s gespeichert!\n", TEXT_STATS);
    fclose(finp);
    fclose(foutp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I could collect data for the numbers?

Comment: I changed the answer. Remember to give size to 'numbers' and you need incude ctype.h too.

Comment: I edited the code with your solution, now it wont do anything after writing the path of the input file.

Comment: I changed the answer again.